# multithreading overhead with mutually independent threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, performance, c++11

I'm currently learning about multi-threading features introduced in c++11 and as I was sifting through several SO questions and I found multi-threading brings its own overhead alongside the executing instructions. So I wrote a simple program to compare b/w sequential and multithreaded solution. The conclusion didn't surprised me, sequential was way-way faster than multi-threaded one, probably because it didn't have to deal with creation and management of threads.

But now for another problem, where sequential approach blocks the whole program, multi-threaded one might get an edge -

**`input.txt`**

```
DEVICE#1 4
DEVICE#2 5
DEVICE#3 10
DEVICE#4 1
DEVICE#1 1
```

**`prog_seq.cpp`**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

using string = std::string;
using namespace std::this_thread;  // sleep_for

void executor(string name, int delay)
{
    sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(delay));
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    string deviceName = "";
    int delay         = 0;

    std::ifstream in("input.txt");

    while (in >> deviceName >> delay) {
        executor(deviceName, delay);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**`Output`**

```
DEVICE#1
DEVICE#2
DEVICE#3
DEVICE#4
DEVICE#1

real    0m21.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

This program will take atleast 21secs to finish, while the following one will probably finish under 11secs-

**`prog_thread.cpp`**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using string = std::string;
using namespace std::this_thread;  // sleep_for

void executor(string name, int delay)
{
    sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(delay));
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threadStore;
    string deviceName = "";
    int delay         = 0;

    std::ifstream in("input.txt");

    while (in >> deviceName >> delay) {
        threadStore.emplace_back(std::thread(executor, deviceName, delay));
    }

    for (auto &t : threadStore) {
        t.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**`Output`**

```
DEVICE#1
DEVICE#4
DEVICE#1
DEVICE#2
DEVICE#3

real    0m10.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

So I understand that for such programs, multi-threaded will actually benefit since they'll get completed in shortest order, given they're switched in good manner (if their number grows higher than cores).

Now what I wanted to ask is, for such programs where each thread is executing mutually independent tasks that aren't exactly *cpu intensive*, but depend more on waiting for inputs or responses from external systems/humans, does the overhead of multi-threading still applies here? Say I have 50 threads all just waiting for input from 50 clients, and since they're *not* busy doing cpu intensive tasks, would this be a better solution vs some sort of timer in sequential execution(which keeps checking for input after 300msecs again and again).

*Also, are there more alternatives to handle such problems, because I would love to know about them.*

Comment: _"Say I have 50 threads all just waiting for input from 50 clients"_ This is the situation with many web server programs, they usually have a thread pool where one thread uses each single connection. Besides that I'm afraid your question is too broad to be answered here concisely. There are too many factors.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ by threadpool you refer to self created fixed amount of threads? or some sort of thread pool managed by OS?

Comment: Usually thread pools are self created in the program.

Comment: I would like to know about the factors themselves. Are there any resources to read upon this? Any tools that can measure these overheads, apart from naive example I've done. My knowledge limits me till here and that's why I've asked this question on SO.

Comment: Asking for 3rd party resources or tools is off-topic here unfortunately.

Comment: This question is far too broad: it would take a book to answer.  Fortunately somebody already wrote it: *"C++ Concurrency in action"* from [Anthony Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5597/anthony-williams).  It's excellent and the author sometimes even answer SO questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, threading management is a very broad and well studied topic in Comp Sci.  For the situation you site, I can give a few industry examples that you might find illustrative however.

In general, having many threads that are I/O bound is a simple and maintainable solution from a programmers standpoint.  Starting a thread per socket connection is a common example. So long as the threads are doing a substantial amount of work over time, the thread setup/tear down is inconsequential.  Typically the Linux scheduler will do a decent job of serving all of the threads.  This model is particularly nice when the thread can wait on a blocking resource like a socket read.  If all the threads are very busy then then model is no good, the time spent context switching will be substantial.  Depending on the latency window, some threads may timeout as well since preemption will be common.

At the other end of the spectrum, the [Reactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) model can be used with a small set of the threads.  In this model, a thread per cpu core is started.  The thread is run 'hot' and no blocking is allowed.  Many clients can be served in a single Reactor in a round robin or similar fashion. Multiple independent Reactors can be started to scale the system.  This model is nice if all the clients are busy all the time with little I/O.  A Reactor model is best for latency sensitive applications. A particular job will be accepted by the Reactor and run to completion with no preemption.

The [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js#Threading) engine uses a similar model to the Reactor, called the [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  The two patterns are similar but not quite the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454642/observer-pattern-vs-reactor-pattern).

The downside of the Reactor/Observer model is the asynchronous nature of the job processing.  Many business applications have a natural blocking or looping point. Having to restructure the algorithm to be asynchronous is often confusing and impacts maintainability. A brief survey of the Node literature will reveal an obsession with asynch algorithms. The threading pattern is a key reason.

Thread management is closely related to Queuing Theory.  The best thread model for a business application is often an expression of the queuing model of the incoming jobs.  [Queuing Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory) is a complex and interesting field.

In summary, for large scale, high throughput and/or low latency applications the threading model is a critical architecture decision. A thorough understanding of both the business problem and the underlying computer science is required to field a successful solution.  See a bit more on this topic on my [blog](http://matthewericfisher.tumblr.com/post/33854949531/a-case-for-minimal-multithreading).