# Name of the classes to implement observer pattern in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, observer-pattern, reactor

What are the names of the classes in .NET library that implement the [observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) publish-subscribe pattern?

I understand that [Rx.NET](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) is implemented with [reactor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) and there are differences between [observer and reactor pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454642/observer-pattern-vs-reactor-pattern).

**Update after selecting an answer:**

This question received 3 votes to close. I don't know whether the reason is because there is no answer for this question. Here is what I know from the answer that *Václav Struhár* posted and from further reading.

The Observable is a word used in many frameworks and languages. In Java, there is an [Observable](http://frankraiser.de/wordpress/?p=112). .NET has [IObservable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.103).aspx) which is available from the `System` namespace.

The observer pattern can be implemented in C# with the `IObservable` generic interface. The Rx.NET has `Observable` extension methods for `System.IObservable<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own [Observer Design Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee850490(v=vs.110).aspx) without usage of any .NET classes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement IObservable< T > and IObserver< T > interfaces, because .NET framework doesn't have built-in observer pattern. Here is an example provided by Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee850490(v=vs.110).aspx